# Rails fetch oauth token and extra fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am trying to fetch oauth token but unable to do so. I am using omniauth for login using facebook.I am able to login in but i want to fetch functionalities like profile data of user.So thats why i want to fetch token Here is my code 
[omniauth.rb]

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'my-app-key', 'my-app-id', {:client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}
end
```

[user.rb]

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider 
    user.uid      = auth.uid
    user.name     = auth.info.name
    user
    user.save
  end
end


end
```

[application_controller]

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception


  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

end
```

[session_controller]

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create

    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the desired parameters in the initializer. Please see [scope](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) in the docs for more details

`config/initializers/omniauth.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook,ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"], ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET_ID"],
           {:scope => 'email, public_profile, user_friends',
            :secure_image_url => true}
end
```

Comment: DO i need to remove this line   provider :facebook, 'my-app-key', 'my-app-id', {:client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}

Comment: no, you can replace with the above code. however you do need to replace the environment variables with your `app_id` and `secret_id`

Comment: you can save down whatever you like. you can view the response by putting a debugger right above `user.provider = auth.provider `